# ToString() and .replace in one line?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to combine these two lines of code into one?

Meaning, can we do a ToString() and .replace() in one line?

```
var mySecondVar = myFirstVar.ToString()
mySecondVar = mySecondVar.replace("a","u");
```

Comment: Have you actually tried?

Comment: What is `myFirstVar` value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can chain the methods.

```
myFirstVar.toString().replace('a', 'u')
```

**Note:**

1. `ToString` should be [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)
2. [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) will only replace the first occurrence of the string. To replace all occurrences use replace with RegEx

Comment: that worked.Thank you. I was trying different ways unsuccessfully. Maybe I should have shown that in the question to silence the "what have you tried" crowd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 var mySecondVar = myFirstVar.toString().replace("a","u");
```